# How massive does a satellite have to be in order to shift the earth's orbit around the sun?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, estimation, celestial-mechanics

How massive does a satellite have to be in order to shift the earth's orbit around the sun? I am wondering how massive a satellite has to be in order to be able to shift the orbit of the earth by rotating around it. I heard it would be possible, but it would be a difficult task, but how massive does it have to be in order to be able to do that? Could you provide real-life example of something massive enough to do that, or perhaps fictional examples from science-fiction movies?

Comment: There isn’t some magic mass above which the orbit is affected. For a small mass there is a small effect. For a large mass there is a large effect.

Comment: The center of mass of the Earth-Moon system (and everything in orbit) follows a smooth elliptical orbit around the sun.  Nothing we do within the system will change that.

Comment: The moon is an example.  But also would any satellite if you allow for small enough effect.

Answer (score 1):

How much the earth will displaced by the satellite
depends not only on the mass of the satellite,
but also on its distance from the earth.

According to Wikipedia "[Barycenter - Two-body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycenter#Two-body_problem)" the shift
of the earth can be calculated by
$$ r_1 = a \cdot \frac{m_2}{m_1 + m_2} = \frac{a}{1+\frac{m_1}{m_2}}$$
where $r_1$ is the shift of the earth,
$a$  is the distance between the centers of earth and satellite,
$m_1$ and $m_2$ are the masses of the earth and satellite.

Because of the large mass of the earth ($m_1 = 6\cdot 10^{24}\ \text{kg}$)
the shift of the earth by a man-made satellite is unmeasurable small
($r_1 \approx 10^{-13}\ \text{m}$),
even if its mass $m_2$ is many tons and its distance $a$ is many thousand km.
You should insert some numbers into the formula above and do the calculation
by yourself.

Another real-life example is the moon which is also a satellite
orbiting the earth.
According to the same Wikipedia article
"[Barycenter - Primary secondary examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycenter#Primary%E2%80%93secondary_examples)"
the shift of the earth due to the moon is $4670\ \text{km}$.